# Should exception logging subsystem have limited throughput ? If yes, how?

Tags: exception, architecture, logging, log4j, log4net

We had a case when exceptions had gone in some kind of infinite loop. 
Stack traces were very big and we log all of them.

That flood our Oracle database and when redo logs reached their size limit db stopped.

EDIT: Of course that the most important thing is to find the cause of infinite loop an correct the bug in the system. We already did that and that is not the question here. 
The system could have more bugs like that (it's an windows service and it's running constantly) and in that case one app broke the whole DB, meaning all applications on that Oracle DB.

I'm mostly interested in your experiences, architecturally. And that from other logging frameworks like log4net, log4j and others. How do they handle flood of exceptions ? Just handle them like all other exceptions ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd worry more about the root cause of the infinite loop then I would about limiting logging.

I'd check your code for methods that catch an exception, log the stack trace, and re-throw.  I'd argue that catching and re-throwing is not exception handling.  If a class truly can't handle the exception, it's better to let it simply bubble up until it reaches a single point where someone can deal with it.

Redo logs?  How often do you flush those?  Surely you don't have one big transaction, do you?

Comment: +1 for emphasizing on how the 'handling' may be unintentionally causing this.

Comment: no, we don't have one big transaction. In this case that was an development DB and redo logs AFAIK are flushed every day of few days (it's automated).

Answer (score 2):

I think your situation illustrates that there should definitely be some mechanism in place to prevent exception logs from causing a denial-of-service anywhere, as this has done.

If you use the Windows event logs, this can be handled for you automatically, as old records can automatically be wiped out when the log is full. You could code a DB-based system to do the same thing, as well.

Of course, you want to do everything you can to eliminate such errors in the first place where ever possible, too!

Another option may be to detect and ignore multiple, consecutive errors of the same time... perhaps simply updating a `count` property/field instead.

Comment: I'd rather not wipe out exceptions because then I could erase data that could help me find the root cause of problem in code.

Comment: If you need all of the exceptions, then you need all of the exceptions and your question seems rather silly.

Comment: So your only option is not to write all exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do the logging to a different database with no redo logs? That will protect the production database.

In our applications whe have a central exceptionhandler where all execeptions go through

```
  void OnExceptionOccurs(Exception ex, 
         string enduserFriendlyContextDescription, 
         string tecnicalContextDescription, 
         ILogger loggerBelongingToProcess)
```

that handler can decide how to log and you have a central location for breakpoint when debugging

Comment: Nice idea, but no, we can't have separate db for logging.